# Reading .txt for separate variables in Python 3.3

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, file-io

I am doing a code for some course work which involves me setting some variables and saving them to a text document (which I did) and it looks like this for every character save:

```
['luxembourg', 'DragonBorn', 14, 11]
```

But how can I get it to read this text document with is list of data and set the 4 things as differently named variables?
(I know how to read text documents and set the entire thing as one variable.)

Comment: You need to fix this by fixing the code that's writing the file - so that it doesn't write `['luxembourg', 'DragonBorn', 14, 11]` but writes `luxembourg, DragonBorn, 14, 11`. Then use normal file reading to read the line and then `.split(',')` will give you each item. You can then save them individually: `city, name, num1, num2 = 'luxembourg, DragonBorn, 14, 11'.split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely use `ast.literal_eval()` (in preference to a regular and dangerous `eval()`) to load the list from your file and unpack into individual variables like this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> a, b, c, d = ast.literal_eval(open('file.txt').read())
>>> a
'luxembourg'
>>> b
'DragonBorn'
>>> c
14
>>> d
11
```

Of course there are any number of other ways to store this data in a file that does not require evaluating it again, e.g. CSV file, a pickle file, json, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a python list containing `['luxembourg', 'DragonBorn', 14, 11]`, just extract them like so:

```
>>> l = ['luxembourg', 'DragonBorn', 14, 11]
>>> city, name, a, b = l
```

Comment: He doesn't have a Python list, he is reading from a file.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid "I know how to read text documents and set the entire thing as one variable." does not really say if he has the whole thing in a string or in a real list.

Comment: _"But how can I get it to read this text document with is list of data "_